# Create Nested Dictionary With Running Total

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to create a nested dictionary that keeps count of totals from a tuple. The outer key will be the product id. The nest dictionary will be keyed by the month and sum of crashes that occur during that month.

Example: Values in tuples are: (product id,date,number of crashes)

```
outages = [
    ('A','2018-01-01', 20),
    ('A','2018-01-01', 20),
    ('A','2018-01-01', 20),
    ('B','2018-01-15', 80),
    ('B','2018-01-19', 200),
    ('A','2018-02-08', 15),
    ('A','2018-02-09', 15),
    ('B','2018-02-15', 80),
    ('B','2018-02-15', 90),
    ('B','2018-02-20', 10),
    ('C','2018-02-25', 120),
    ('A','2018-03-01', 10),
    ('B','2018-04-01', 10),
    ('C','2018-03-01', 5)]
```

My expected output is:

```
{'A': {1: 60, 2: 30, 3: 10}, 'B': {1: 280, 2: 180, 4: 10}, 'C': {2: 120, 3: 5}}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
from datetime import datetime

#Create a class to implement missing method for when key is not in the dictionary 
class NestedDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = NestedDict()
        return self[key]

#Create Instance of NestedDict
nested_dic=NestedDict()

#Loop through outages and created outer and inner key
for x in outages:
    nested_dic[x[0]][datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d').month] = 0 #=>Need Help Here
```

I'm uncertain where to go from here to get the desired output. I'm setting the values to 0 because performing: `+= x[2]` instead gives me an error. Ideally, I want to iterate through `outages` and updated the dictionary after scanning each tuple instead of having to iterate over multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be pretty terse if you don't mind using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). The idea is to extract the month, convert it to `int` and accumulate on each nested dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

outages_by_month = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for prod_id, date, crashes in outages:
    outages_by_month[prod_id][int(date[5:7])] += crashes

print(outages_by_month)
```

If you want normal `dict`s (`NestedDict` feels like an unnecessary abstraction), either build them that way from the start (set default keys by hand), or use something like:

```
outages_by_month = {k: dict(v) for k, v in outages_by_month.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'A': {1: 60, 2: 30, 3: 10}, 'B': {1: 280, 2: 180, 4: 10}, 'C': {2: 120, 3: 5}}
```

Comment: Could use `defaultdict(Counter)` instead of `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections` and extend `MutableMapping` which is an abstract class that has the interface of a python dictionary. The idea was to override a `python dictionary` and customize the `__setitem__` method: that's the only method that needs to be implemented thoughtfully..

```
import collections


class RunningSumDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._d = {}
        if args:
            self._d[args[0]] = args[1]
        if kwargs:
            self._d = kwargs

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._d.get(key)

    """
    key: month
    val: crashes
    """

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if key in self._d:
            self._d[key] = self._d[key] + val
        else:
            self._d[key] = val

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._d[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._d)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._d)

    def get(self):
        return self._d

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._d == other

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._d)


class OuterDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._d = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._d.get(key)

    """
    key: product id
    val: tuple(month, crashes)
    """

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if key in self._d:
            sum_dict = self._d[key]
            sum_dict[val[0]] = val[1]
            self._d[key] = sum_dict
        else:
            self._d[key] = RunningSumDict(*val)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._d[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._d)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._d)

    def get(self):
        return self._d

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._d == other

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._d)


def running_sum(outages):
    # Get the months only for the second entry
    outages = [(outage[0], outage[1].split('-')[1], outage[2])
               for outage in outages]

    som = OuterDict()
    for outage in outages:
        som[outage[0]] = (outage[1], outage[2])
    return som


if __name__ == "__main__":
    outages = [
        ('A', '2018-01-01', 20),
        ('A', '2018-01-01', 20),
        ('A', '2018-01-01', 20),
        ('B', '2018-01-15', 80),
        ('B', '2018-01-19', 200),
        ('A', '2018-02-08', 15),
        ('A', '2018-02-09', 15),
        ('B', '2018-02-15', 80),
        ('B', '2018-02-15', 90),
        ('B', '2018-02-20', 10),
        ('C', '2018-02-25', 120),
        ('A', '2018-03-01', 10),
        ('B', '2018-04-01', 10),
        ('C', '2018-03-01', 5)]

    print(running_sum(outages))
```

**Result**

```
{'A': {'01': 60, '02': 30, '03': 10}, 'B': {'01': 280, '02': 180, '04': 10}, 'C': {'02': 120, '03': 5}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm going to digest this a bit further but I'm curious to know, what is the advantage of this over the answer @ggorlen gave?

Comment: It's style. Style of programming and ease to understand for a biginner. And helps introduce to how to extend a python collections class and override some of the funder methods and still get a near python dict behaviour. But foremost  it  is just for ease.